# Integratethe following function: $\int \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(x+n)}dx, n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, polynomials

> Integrate the following function:
> $$\int \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(x+n)}dx, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I saw this question as an exercise on a University of Colorado website, and I'm not quite sure how to solve this. My first instinct was do this integral step-by-step. So first determine $\int\frac{1}{x}dx$, then $\int\frac{1}{x(x+1)}dx$, so on in order to notice a pattern and then use induction to prove it but I'm hopping there is a more concrete way to find the solution.

Comment: @SkiMask Indefinite integral, correct?

Comment: @Ty. Yes, it's indefinite.

Comment: Doing partial fractions. You will see the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use the identity that
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)...(x+n)}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{k{n \choose k}}{x+k}.$$
Let
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)...(x+n)}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{k{n \choose k}}{x(x+k)}.$$
$$\implies g(x)=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} {n \choose k} \left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+k}\right)$$
$$\implies g(x)=\frac{1}{n! x}-\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1} \frac{{n \choose k}}{x+k}.$$
Finally, $$\int g(x) dx=\frac{1}{n!}\left(\ln x+\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k} {n \choose k} \ln(x+k)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You do not need induction.

You can calculate the PFD directly using the limit-method:

$$\frac 1{\prod_{k=0}^n(x+k)} = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{A_k}{x+k}$$

Now, you have

$$A_k = \lim_{x\to -k}\frac{x+k}{\prod_{i=0}^n(x+i)}= \frac 1{\prod_{i=0,i\neq k}^n(i-k)}$$

So, you need only to integrate

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac 1{\prod_{i=0,i\neq k}^n(i-k)}\cdot \frac 1{x+k}\right)$$